# Scons running py.test in different subdirectories

Tags: python, scons, pytest

We have a large repository containing several Python packages(*).  I want scons to run [py.test](http://pytest.org/latest/) in each of the sub directories and not from the project root.  This is proving rather frustrating.  Currently, I have this action with all error checking removed:

```
def runTests (target = None, source = None, env = None):
    cmd = which(env['TEST_RUNNER'])
    if cmd:
        retCode = True
        for path in env['TEST_DIR_LIST']:
            print 'Doing directory %s:' % (path)
            retCode = retCode and subprocess.call([cmd], cwd=path)
        env.Exit(retCode)
```

Which I call as in the `SConstruct` file:

```
runTestsCmd = env.Command('runTests', None, Action(runTests, "Running tests"))
AlwaysBuild(runTestsCmd)
Alias('test', runTestsCmd)
```

And in each `SConscript` file, I have this:

```
env.Append(TEST_DIR_LIST = ['PackageDirectory'])
```

What I get is that only one instance of py.test is run.  I can see the "Doing directory X" messages but no run of py.test.

Clearly, there is a need to not clone the environment in SConscript or if the env is cloned, making sure that the addition to TEST_DIR_LIST happens on original env.

So, my questions are two fold:

1. **Is this a sensible way of doing what I want**?
2. If it is, **What am I doing wrong**?  If it is not, **what should I be doing**?

(*) *Yes, we are looking at changing this. No, it will not happens soon enough so I do need the above.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
retCode = retCode and subprocess.call([cmd], cwd=path)
```

`subprocess.call` returns 0 (which evaluates to `False`) on success.  You need to insert a `not` or maybe do a proper check like this:

```
retcode = subprocess.call([cmd], cwd=path)
if retcode != 0:
     print ("failed ...")
     break  # or not break if you want to continue anyway
```

Comment: Indeed.  I realised that late last night.  Thank!